# Which do I accept? the answer with more votes or more information?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question:

[How do I properly care for my paintbrushes?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/4222/how-do-i-properly-care-for-my-paintbrushes)

And the shorter answer has more votes.  The other one has more information and it was more comprehensive, is it okay to accept that one even though it has fewer votes? Or do I have to accept the one with more votes?

Another question addresses when to accept an answer, however I'm not sure about which one to choose.  I want to choose the one with the fewer votes, but that goes against the community opinion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I accept an answer?](http://meta.woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/156/when-should-i-accept-an-answer)

Comment: From my answer to the linked question: _Mark the one that __you think helps you.___

Comment: Agree with @Matt. on Stack Exchange, the user that asks the question is the one to choose an answer. Often there are multiple good answers; or the situation is unusual enough that it goes against the community. Sometimes there are no good answers, or there are informative answers that don't really answer the question. In that case, don't mark an answer as someone else may still answer it.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion....

There are often multiple answers that are very good, but different.  Questioners often do not select any of the answers as "The" answer.  This meta Question/answer ([When should I accept an answer?](https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/when-should-i-accept-an-answer?rq=1)) expresses this very well.